# Question about random variables

Tags: probability

I'm new in a probability course and I stuck with the following questions.  The problems stipulate:

In a store there are 10 printers such that 4 are defective, 6 are good and one company buy 5 of them.

First question:  What is the probability for choice 5 that are good, and I realize that this is a random variable whit hypergeometric distribution and the answer is 0.02381.

Second question:  If the company decides repair the defective printers at cost of 50 dollars each one, find the expectation and variance of the cost of such repairs.

Comment: Are you OK with the first problem?  Or are you stuck knowing that it's hypergeometric and also knowing the answer, but not knowing how they got there?

Comment: Yes I'm OK whit first question, I just did the calculation my problem is how to deal whit the random variable of reparation cost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Basic approach.**  Use the same hypergeometric distribution you used for the first question to determine

$$
p_k \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} P(\text{out of the $5$ chosen printers, exactly $k$ are bad})
$$

Note then that also $p_k = P(\text{repairs cost $50k$ dollars})$.  So you can easily determine expected total cost $C$ as

$$
E(C) = \sum_{k=0}^4 50k p_k
$$

Find $E(C^2)$ in a similar way, and then

$$
\sigma^2_C = E(C^2)-[E(C)]^2
$$

Answer (score 1):

For a Hypergeometric distribution, $X\sim\mathcal {Hyp}(N,K,n)$, where $N$ is the population size, $K$ the 'success' population size, and $n$ the sample size, we have: $$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X)&=\dfrac{nK}{N}\\[1ex]\mathsf{Var}(X)&=\dfrac{nK(N-k)(N-n)}{N^2(N-1)}\end{align}$$

You seek $\mathsf E(50(5-X))$ and $\mathsf{Var}(50(5-X))$ where $X\sim\mathcal{Hyp}(10,6,5)$; the count of good units in a sample of $5$ extracted from a population of $10$ units containing $6$ good units.